# Transform simple string in a key: value array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've the following string in the JavaScript:

```
test: hi,
otherTest: hiAgain
```

How can I transform in a key: value array?

Comment: looking for [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: But how to do? I'm already using `split` to separate the string on the commas but I don't know how to do separate in a key: value array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

```js
var str='test: hi,\notherTest: hiAgain';

var obj={};
var kvp=str.split('\n');
for(k=0;k<kvp.length;k++){
  var temp=kvp[k].split(' ');
  obj[temp[0]]=temp[1];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var string = 'test: hi,otherTest: hiAgain';
var sets = string.split(","); //splits string by commas
var out = new Array(); //prepare the output array
for (var i=0; i<sets.length; i++) {
  var keyval = sets[i].split(":"); //split by colon for key/val
  out[keyval[0]] = keyval[1].trim(); //trim off white spaces and set array
}
```

Comment: an Array is not required here, as keys will be string (adding propertie to the object) and not indexes. And the length will not be updated as you don't `push` to the array

Comment: @Hacketo except the question specifically asks for an array. Also the length should not update. It is taking the original string and breaking it up to create the new array. Push is not required if you know the key you are setting it to.

Comment: OP is asking for a 'key:value array', and that does not exist in javascript, it's a raw object.

Comment: @Hacketo ah i misunderstood. I thought he meant key:value as in the format of how he wanted the array broken up.

Comment: You code is right, it's just the type of 'out', a raw object would do the same, without any misunderstand about arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
var data = ['test: hi', 'otherTest: hiAgain'];
var result = [];
$.each(data, function(index, value){
    var keyValue = value.split(':');
    var obj = {};
    obj[keyValue[0].trim()] = keyValue[1].trim();
    result.push(obj);
});
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Hope this help.